# How to start effect from update function?

Tags: elm

I declared update function:

```
update : Action -> Model -> (Model, Effects.Effects Action)
```

And my model is:

```
model = Signal.foldp update init actions.signal
```

But Signal.foldp expects update function with Action -> Model -> Model shape.

Effect is POST call with code:

```
Http.post Json.Decode.string "http://localhost/tracker/link-admin/test.php" body 
|> Task.toMaybe 
|> Task.map SetShortenedUrl 
|> Effects.task
```

I have two questions:

1. how can I run effect from update?
2. how can I change my model to type check?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be using `Effects` without `StartApp`, at some point you'll need to use [`Effects.toTask`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-effects/latest/Effects#toTask), which requires a mailbox that can accept a list of actions.

Note that the [documentation of `Effects.toTask`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-effects/latest/Effects#toTask) warns away from its explicit use except by expert hands (full disclosure: *I am no expert*) and at most once per app, but I'm going to pick it apart here anyways as an exercise in understanding StartApp.

Using the [`StartApp` source code](https://github.com/evancz/start-app/blob/master/src/StartApp.elm) as our guide, we can pick out just the bare minimum we need to get your example running. First off, we have to deal with the pesky mailbox problem by defining a second mailbox called `messages` that takes a list of actions.

```elm
messages =
  Signal.mailbox []
```

Now, we have to redefine your `actions` mailbox in terms of this new `messages` mailbox, using only the first element of the list, or `NoOp` in case of an empty list. (Read up on [`Effects.toTask`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-effects/latest/Effects#toTask) to understand why it is a list, and why we're ok in this example to treat it as a singleton list)

```elm
actions : Signal.Mailbox Action
actions =
  let
    singleton action =
      [action]
    fromList list =
      case list of
        [] -> NoOp
        (action::_) -> action
  in
    { address = Signal.forwardTo messages.address singleton
    , signal = Signal.map fromList messages.signal
    }
```

We'll need a new Signal to deal with Effects so we can split out the processing in the `update` function from the tasks which we'll soon send to a port. Again, picking snippets from `StartApp`, we can define the following signal

```elm
effectsAndModel : Signal (Model, Effects.Effects Action)
effectsAndModel =
  let
    updateJustModel action (model,_) = update action model
  in
    Signal.foldp updateJustModel init actions.signal
```

Now that we have the above `effectsAndModel` signal, we can now redefine your `model` signal by just peeling off the Model from the first element of the tuple.

```elm
model : Signal Model
model =
  Signal.map fst effectsAndModel
```

Likewise, we can use the `effectsAndModel` signal to send the tasks out a port by peeling off the Effects from the second element of the tuple:

```elm
port tasks : Signal (Task.Task Effects.Never ())
port tasks =
  Signal.map (Effects.toTask messages.address << snd) effectsAndModel
```

The above port, `tasks` is where the `Effects.toTask` happens which required the redefining of your `actions` mailbox.

I've created a simple working example with an ad hoc `view` method to verify your requirements at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/freakingawesome/176e5b05e523e9275cb4). I changed it to look for a local test.txt file rather than your url.